# Generate Q-type from Class object in QueryDSL

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I have a method which returns the Class object of entity I want to query:

```
protected abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();
```

and later I would like to query this entity with QueryDSL

```
new JPAQuery<>(em).from(?????);
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out I can use PathBuilder:

```
PathBuilder<Person> pathBuilder = new PathBuilder(Person.class, "PERSON");

List<Person> fetch = new JPAQuery<Person>(em)
                .from(pathBuilder)
                .fetch();
```